# ToolBar label and TabLayout not formatted correctly

Tags: android

I need to create a header on a fragment that looks like this:
[image]

But my xml must not be correct as I'm getting margins I did not specify

### Layout for the fragment

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/serviceOpportunitiesToolbar"
            style="@style/Toolbar.CustomContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ThemeOverlay.Toolbar.Main">


            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/interestTabs"
                style="@style/TabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="@{showInterests ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE}" />


        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

what that layout produces is this, with the tabLayout below the label but with a margin on the left and top I did not specify:
[image]

What do I need to do with my layout to remove the margins between toolbar and tabLayout?

Koswarm suggested I put the tablayout below and outside the toolbar. but that results in an entirely new view inserted between the title and tablayout, although it does solve the margins issue
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Place the TabLayout below the toolbar (Not inside)

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/serviceOpportunitiesToolbar"
    style="@style/Toolbar.CustomContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ThemeOverlay.Toolbar.Main">
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/interestTabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/TabLayout"
    android:visibility="@{showInterests ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE}"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/serviceOpportunitiesToolbar" />
```

Comment: While that does remove the gaps on the left and top, it created and entirely new view between the title and tablayout.  I'll update my question with an image showing it